# Add-on won't show up?

Tags: add-on

I've been trying so hard to add this add-on into blender but no matter how hard I try it just won't show up. I've followed all the tutorials, searched through this site, and restarted blender completely but nothing will work. I'm pretty new to blender but from my understanding it shouldn't be this hard, so what am I doing wrong? Here is the add-on I'm trying to add: https://osdn.net/projects/meshio/releases/ [image: This is the add-on screen right?] [image: And this is where I try and add the file. But whenever I click 'install add-on from file', it takes me to the same screen as before, with no changes.]

(First image) This is the add-on screen right?
(Second image) And this is where I try and add the file. But whenever I click 'install add-on from file', it takes me to the same screen as before, with no changes.

Comment: The add-on seems to be for Blender 2.5x. It might not be compatible with your version of Blender. It also lists Windows XP as requirement.

Comment: @RobertGützkow I tried downloading a version that should be compatible with my blender, but it still won't show up